# React setting state with async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

So I am setting my state in my constructor with:

```
constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    const nav = NavService.getNav();
    const user = AuthService.getProfile();

    this.state = {
        activeNav: 0,
        nav: nav ? nav : [],
        showDropdown: false,
        showNavDropdown: false,
        user: user ? user : [],
    };
}
```

However, I am noticing some async issues so I want to make getNav() and getProfile() async and await them. Obviously I can't do this in the constructor because constructors cannot be async and therefore I cannot use await. Now I know I can just throw this into an `async componentDidMount()` but this causes a double `render()`. How can I optimize this?

Comment: Preload data before mounting a component at all (render `null` or a placeholder)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a re-render will be hard to avoid if your have to load some data asynchronously.

You could keep an additional state variable `loading` and just return `null` in the render method until your data has loaded.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeNav: 0,
    nav: [],
    showDropdown: false,
    showNavDropdown: false,
    user: [],
    loading: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all(NavService.getNav(), AuthService.getProfile())
      .then(([nav, user]) => {
        this.setState({ nav, user, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      activeNav,
      nav,
      showDropdown,
      showNavDropdown,
      user,
      loading
    } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return null;
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this looks like the best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: What I ended up doing was have componentDidMount be an async function and then in render if (nav && user) return my component, otherwise return null. Works great.